# How to make a quiz with answers from an external file?

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to make a quiz but my answers are in an external file, so but everytime I run it with my correct answers they say they are incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
randNum = int(random.randint(0, 4))

song = open("songList.csv","rt")

with open("songList.csv", "rt") as f:

songn = str(song.readlines()[randNum])
reader= csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
   print (songn[0])

guess = input("What is the song called?")
score = 0
correct_guess = False
while True:
    if guess == songn:
        correct_guess = True
        break

    score += 1
    if score>=total:
        break
    song_guess = input("Incorrect! Try again:\n> ")
if correct_guess:
    print("Answer correct!")
else:
    print("game over")
```

Comment: Can your print guess and songn? When I test it it works correctly.

Comment: Does `songn` have a newline character at the end?

Comment: when you read lines from the file they come with New Line char at the end. Your input does not, so they are never the same

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you have trailing newline characters in one of the strings. Hence they aren't equal.

However I wouldn't just remove the newline. It is always good practice, if your logic allows it, to normalize strings before you test for equality. There are lots of things you can do to normalize:

```
def normalize(string):
    string = string.strip()  # Remove any leading or trailing whitespaces
    string = string.lower()  # Make all letters lowercase 
    string = " ".join(string.split())  # If the user hit spacebar twice, for example, will remove the double space. Note can have side effects.
    return string
```

Then check

```
if normalize(string1) == normalize(string2):
    do_something()
```

In fact, if you are dealing with user input, even this might not be sufficient. For example, if the user makes a typo, it won't match.

So I recommend also looking at the fuzzywuzzy library

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz 

def similar(string1, string2):
    ratio = fuzz.ratio(string1, string2)
    return ratio >= 85  # number between 0 and 100. Higher means fewer differences are allowed
```

Fuzzywuzzy is very powerful and easy to use. For more info: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy